# Sort a binary file

Tags: c, sorting

I need to sort a binary file using external sort. I use 2 aux files f1 and f2 where i put monotonous sequence data. After that i merge this files. I do this until there is one monotonous sequence.

EX 1 2 3 4 5 0 1

f1: 1 2 3 4 5
f2: 0 1

final file 0 1 1 2 3 4 5

I need some hints

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Just saying "I need some hints" is way too vague.

Comment: I don't know how to distribute those monotonous sequences in f1 and f2. My file contains numbers of type unsigned long

Comment: OK - and what do you need to know ? What sorting algorithm to use ? How to code it in whatever programming language you are using ? Try and improve your question and you may get some helpful answers.

Comment: Ok. I need to do this in C. I need an algorithm. For example if i have file1: 1 2 3 0 1 and file2:0 2 I need to know how to merge this files to obtain a sorted file

Comment: OK - I've added a `c` tag for you now - try and remember to tag with programming language in future questions. You might also want to read up on similar questions on SO that have already been answered, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array

Comment: Start by reading each file as an array of `unsigned long`. Then try to figure out how to merge and sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read files `f1` and `f2` into arrays `a1` and `a2`.
2. Sort arrays `a1` and `a2`.
3. Walk through both arrays element by element, adding the lowest element from each array to output array. As you add an element, increment your "walk-index" for that array.
4. Print output array to file.