# How to most efficiently merge and sort arrays of dicts with datetime in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assume I have the following 3 arrays which are sorted in ascending order by `exercisedateandtime`:

```
var listA = [
  {name: "Mike", exercisedateandtime: 1299233593000, exercise: "Jumping Jacks"}, 
  {name: "Mike", exercisedateandtime: 1299237012000, exercise: "Running"}
];

var listB = [
  {name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299233712000, exercise: "Swimming"},
  {name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299233831000, exercise: "Swimming"},
  {name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299240620000, exercise: "Swimming"}
];

var listC = [
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299237320000, exercise: "Fishing"},
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299237611000, exercise: "Motor Boating"},
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299305420000, exercise: "Cycling"}
];
```

What is the most efficient way to merge these lists such that I get a resulting array `listD` is also sorted in ascending order by `exercisedateandtime`? Is it possible to create a function that accepts any number of arrays? (Note: Though the sample provided is small, the ideal method should be handle large list(s) sizes.)

```
var listD = [
{name: "Mike", exercisedateandtime: 1299233593000, exercise: "Jumping Jacks"},
{name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299233712000, exercise: "Swimming"},
{name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299233831000, exercise: "Swimming"},
{name: "Mike", exercisedateandtime: 1299237012000, exercise: "Running"},
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299237320000, exercise: "Fishing"},
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299237611000, exercise: "Motor Boating"},
{name: "Charles", exercisedateandtime: 1299240620000, exercise: "Swimming"},
{name: "William", exercisedateandtime: 1299305420000, exercise: "Cycling"}
];
```

Comment: Yes, assume the lists are ordered by date in ascending order.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array

Comment: Can we rely on the single list to be sorted correctly already? How many lists with how many items are there in average?

Comment: You can rely on each "input" list (like listA, listB, listC... and any others that would be used as input to be sorted correctly by exercisedateandtime already).

Comment: In `listC` "Fishing" should come before "Motor Boating". Edited.

Comment: @Setsuna Please accept an answer. Preferably aaronman's answer or mine. We've put a great deal of effort into explaining and writing code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it is just a slight adaptation of a merge in a normal mergesort (runs in O(n)). Basically how that works is you keep looking at the beginning of each list and and taking the largest the smallest one an appending it to the new list it works exactly the same for three lists . So this is the code from Aadit's solution(same algo as mine), but everyone seems to be up-voting a solution that is significantly slower than this solution and I would like to counter act this so the OP doesn't end up using it in his code.

```
function merge(key) {
    var length = arguments.length, lists = [], newlist = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) lists.push(arguments[i].slice());

    while (length = lists.length) {
        var min = Infinity;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var list = lists[i];
            var value = list[0][key];

            if (value < min) {
                var index = i;
                min = value;
            }
        }

        var list = lists[index];
        newlist.push(list.shift());
        if (!list.length) lists.splice(index, 1);
    }

    return newlist;
}
```

Now you can merge the lists as follows:

```
var listD = merge("exercisedateandtime", listA, listB, listC);
```

Basically how this works is is gets an list of lists and the key that it is supposed to sort by, in this case `exercisedateandtime`. Then it keeps finding the minimum front element of all the list until there are no lists left(the while loop is a little tricky since the `=` returns whatever is the value it is set to when `lists` is 0 it becomes false). This merge will work with any number of lists even if they are different sizes. This algorithm runs in O(n) assuming the list sizes are large enough to make the number of lists negligible.

**EDIT:** in an extremely unideal case where the number of lists is very large, which is not the case here as there are only three lists, and the size of each list is small it might be better to do a solution where the lists are merged like in a merge sort, 2 at a time. The code could be adapted to do this by checking the number of lists but it would be a lot more work to code. I'll also repeat one more time that the original question is for 3 lists so it will work fine for that.

Here is a link to the most ideal [n-way merge](http://dzmitryhuba.blogspot.com/2010/03/n-way-merge.html) I could find

Comment: you are right, it is half the procedure of mergesort if they are already sorted within themselves ..

Comment: yeah in fact if you think about it one could actually adapt merge sort to run with 3 partitions instead of two

Comment: mergesort uses more than one partition by combining each pair. this can be done to 3 partitions too ( (1) (2 3) ) .. it is actually not halfway of the procedure, it is rather the last quarter of the procedure, well assuming all the 3 partitions have the same size ! otherwise re-partitioned to more arrays then processed normally as a mergesort.

Comment: @CME64 are you arguing with me or agreeing?

Comment: Does this handle more arrays of greater size and perform faster/acceptable performance relatively? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: @Setsuna Mine runs in O(n), everyone else's runs O(n*log(n)), I'll try to write an example but I will admit the code is more complex

Comment: @Setsuna also as written Aguardientico's solution doesn't work

Comment: @aaronman My solution runs in `O(n)` time. See it for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17334658/783743

Comment: @AaditMShah it's the same as mine your just less lazy than me and actually coded it

Comment: merge sort is : O(n log n) the normal comparison function is O(n^2)

Comment: the normal function runs as a selectionsort check this link guys : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @AaditMShah: No, it's `O(#lists * avListLen²)` for your solution. The n-way-merge described in the linked question with a priority queue would run in `O(#lists * avListLen * log(avListLen))`. And you cannot do better.

Comment: @Bergi in the spirit of the question #lists is going to be very small, the only reason he wrote it as an n lists merge is because writing a solely three way merge is more trouble than it's worth

Comment: In the spirit of my question, the ideal solution would be preferable for large list sizes to be merged together.

Comment: @Setsuna Yes and my solution and Aadit M Shah's are the only solutions that run in linear time and yet we both have the least upvotes. The first two solutions run in O(n log(n)) and both of ours run in O(n), not sure why the other two solutions are being upvoted

Comment: @Setsuna also looking at your edit I don't think you understood my comment about the number of lists, my solution handles large lists fine, it starts to do slightly worse if the ***number*** of lists is large but still better than the other solutions

Comment: @AaditMShah why bother editing it, the OP has committed to not accepting any answer, and the solution with the most votes is crap

Answer (score 3):

```
var listD = listA.concat(listB, listC).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.exercisedateandtime - b.exercisedateandtime
});
```

Comment: `[] + []` [doesn't result in an `Array`](http://jsconsole.com/?%5B%5D%20%2B%20%5B%5D) in [JavaScript](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1). Though, `[].concat([])` [will](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: @aaronman The `.sort(...)` looks good. Just replace `(lista + listb + listc)` with `lista.concat(listb, listc)`.

Comment: correct answer but it will change listB by merging c into it which is not desired, use a.concat(b).concat(c) .. also consider the optimization of the algorithm as the OP requires.

Comment: This is clean and clear javascript and a good answer but not most efficient.

Comment: This clearly not the most efficient way to do this that has been posted

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed. Try this:

```
function merge(key) {
    var length = arguments.length, lists = [], newlist = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) lists.push(arguments[i].slice());

    while (length = lists.length) {
        var min = Infinity;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var list = lists[i];
            var value = list[0][key];

            if (value < min) {
                var index = i;
                min = value;
            }
        }

        var list = lists[index];
        newlist.push(list.shift());
        if (!list.length) lists.splice(index, 1);
    }

    return newlist;
}
```

Now you can merge the lists as follows:

```
var listD = merge("exercisedateandtime", listA, listB, listC);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/b8WdW/2/

Comment: There +1 for the actually coding it

Comment: Right now the other solution with 2 votes doesn't even work correctly

Comment: @aaronman The first line of the code says that all the arguments after `key` are put into an array called `lists`. Hence calling `merge("exercisedateandtime", listA, listB, listC)` will result in `var lists = [listA, listB, listC]` inside the function.

Comment: @aaronman No, `arguments` is a variable available freely inside every function. See for yourself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: Nice I would code my own solution but it would end up looking the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtTGX/1/)

Basically I merged the arrays first before sorting them. So this should work even if you arrays are unsorted.

```
var listD = listB.concat(listA, listC);
console.log(listD);
listD.sort(function (a, b) {
return a.exercisedateandtime - b.exercisedateandtime
});
console.log(listD);
```

Comment: correct answer but it will change listA by merging c into it which is not desired, use .concat().concat() .. still not fast enough if arrays are huge