# How do I find the intersection of 2 sets?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, set-intersection

What is the most efficient way to create a subset from 2 sets that contains values from both of them? Any C++ STL library can be used to solve this (without Boost library if possible):

```
Set A = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...}
Set B = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...}

Subset should be = {3, 5, 7, 11, ...}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `std::set` already?

Comment: The answer by @bigOTHER is correct, but was this question a "howto" question or an algorithmic one? (if it's algorithmic, and the sets are ordered, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using [`set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), you will find an example there how to use it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{2, 3, 5, 7, 11};;
    std::vector<int> v2{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<int> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
    for(int n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Results will be:

```
 3 5 7 11
```

Comment: At least link the better [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: @LogicStuff updated, thanks

Comment: @bigOTHER I mean that mainly because of the clearer example.

Comment: 11 is missing from the output because of a typical bug that arises when hard-coding values like 5 instead of using `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: @LogicStuff I updated the example

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::set_intersection` as described here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Comment: When looking up C++ documentation I prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) since the first is more often correct than the latter.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember this.