# Enabling ranges if the list<Integers> contains a number with in those ranges (Java)

Tags: java, performance, numbers, range

I have some custom ranges as below:

Range A 3-6

Range B 6-9

Range C 10-11

Range D 12-15

Range E 16-99 (All the ranges are inclusive)

I have a List in a sorted order (low to high). The ranges should be enabled if there is at least one number from the list that fits in the respective ranges

To solve this i have to iterate the list and check whether at least one number fits in the range:

```
for(Integer a:list) {
  if (new Range(3, 6).contains(a.intValue())) {
    available = true; //(for respective range)
    break;                  
  }
}
```

comparing each and every value of list to enable a range seems to be a performance to me. Is there any best solution for this??

I am having a Range object with following attributes

```
private String name;
private int min;
private int max;
private boolean available;
```

3&6 in above snippet is min & max of Range A

Comment: First, move out `new Range(3,6)` of the for loop, these doesn't overload the allocated memory, neither the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no need to do a `contains()` since it will do a search and the best search algorithm will be `O(log n)`  (Binary Search)

Just need to do the comparison (assuming both ranges are inclusive)

```
if (min<= value && value <= max)
```

Which is a constant comparison `O(1)`

Since you will be doing at most for `n` ranges the overall running time will be `O(n)`  instead of  `O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 0):

Given that the ranges are sorted, and assuming that they do not overlap, you can run a binary search on them to find inclusion faster. Use [`Arrays.binarySearch` overload that takes a custom `Comparator<? super T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)).

However, given that you have only five ranges to check, doing a binary search sounds like a premature optimization, which is very likely to be unnecessary.

If the number of ranges and `int`s is large, you may be able to find the ranges to be enabled in a single pass through the list if you are allowed to sort the integers. The idea is to apply an algorithm similar to [merging sorted arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949433/335858). Start at the beginning of the list of `int`s and the list of ranges, and advance indexes in merge-like succession. When an `int` fits in a range, mark the range enabled, and skip all `int`s from the list until you hit the upper end of the range, or exhaust the list of `int`s, whichever comes first.