# java - combine two sorted arrays

Tags: java

I want to combine two sorted arrays, so they just need to be compared and printed out. The problem I have is, that the output is wrong, because the programm just goes through the second for-loop. What do I have to do to make it work?

> result = {1,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10}

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9 };
        int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int i;
        int j;
        int a;
        int b;

        for (j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            a = array1[j];
            for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                b = array2[i];
                if (a < b) {
                    System.out.print(a);
                } else if (b < a) {
                    System.out.print(b);
                } else if (a == b) {
                    System.out.print(a + b);
                }
            }    
        }    
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are using the same index variable _i_ for the both the **for-loop**

Comment: *I want to combine two sorted arrays, so they just need to be compared and printed out* I can't understand what that mean. Combining and comparing look like completely different things to me. Elaborate, with a concrete example.

Comment: both loops contains the same counter variable `i`

Comment: Duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array)

Comment: @Praveen I noticed it, but it doesn't change the problem. It keeps looping the second array over and over and does not compare it to the first one

Comment: what do you want to do? Compare first element of array1 with first element of array2, second with second and so on? What appen if array haven't same number of elements?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of adding equal numbers

Comment: @cricket_007 It should just do it

Comment: @JBNizet I added the result it should print out in this example

Comment: Learn to use the StackOverflow search engine.  The URL is "www.google.com".

Comment: Do what? **adding** numbers is not the same as **merging** arrays

Answer (score 0):

algo --

```
int i=0, j=0, k=0
int[] result = new int[arr1.length+arr2.length];
while (i<arr1.length && j<arr2.length)  {
    if(arr1[i] <= arr2[j]) {
        result[k++] = arr1[i++];
        // or if u just want to print do a sysout. 
    } else {
        result[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
} 

while(i<arr1.length) 
     result[k++] = arr1[i++];

while(j<arr2.length) 
     result[k++] = arr2[j++];
```